# Ionic 2 form validation malfunctioning

Tags: ionic2, angular2-forms

My Ionic 2 form is based on [floating-labels](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#floating-labels).

However, when validation HTML elements are added, they do not show up on the page. The `div` elements below do not show up when validation fails.

Are `div` tags not to be used inside of `<ion-item>`?

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" id="fname" [ngFormControl]="fname"></ion-input>
        <div *ngIf="fname.touched">
            <div *ngIf="fname.errors?.minlength">First name should be atleast 2 characters</div>
            <div *ngIf="fname.errors?.invalidFirstCharacter">First character should be an alphabet</div>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem only seems to occur once you start using `ion-label` inside the `ion-item` element.

There is a [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/confused-about-ion-item-usage/54116/16) about this on the Ionic forum which I have just come across and it provides a more detailed explanation and some workarounds.

> @brandyshea
>
> I believe this is an issue with content projection actually, since it wants to 
>   grab the nested ion-label but it isn't able to place it correctly.

And

> @brandyshea
>
> The item will look for an `ion-label` element and if it exists it will
>   ignore other elements...

**My workaround**

When I came across this my solution was to put validation elements outside of the `ion-item` element, however Ionic have introduced their own solution

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Input 1</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" id="fname" [ngFormControl]="input1"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="input1.touched && input1.errors?.minlength">
    Input 1 must contain at least 2 characters
</div>
```

**Ionic's solution**

In beta 8 Ionic introduced an `item-content` attribute that can be added to an element so it will display inside an `ion-item`. Not tested this one yet but it was mentioned in the post I linked

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Input 1</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" id="fname" [ngFormControl]="input1"></ion-input>
    <div *ngIf="input1.touched && input1.errors?.minlength" item-content>
        Input 1 must contain at least 2 characters
    </div>
</ion-item>
```